# Centering thumbnail gallery with captions without fixed image size

Tags: css, internet-explorer, thumbnails, centering, caption

I've tried unsuccessfully to implement the layout in the attached image. When apllied div with table setting IE brokes, if elements are floated when captions are more than one line the layout is broken again. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.!

Layout image: [image]

Here is the CSS

```
.thumbsHolder {clear:both;float:left;width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
.thumbsHolder ul#prodThumbs {padding-top:20px;margin:0 auto;list-style-type:none;text-align:center;}
.thumbsHolder ul#prodThumbs li {float:left;padding:0 7px;min-height:150px;}
.thumbsHolder ul#prodThumbs li a {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;font-size:70%;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="thumbsHolder">
<ul id="prodThumbs">
<li><a href="link1.htm"><img src="thumb1.jpg" /></a> <!-- image width and height may differ -->
<p><a href="link1.htm">Caption</a></p></li>
<li><a href="link2.htm"><img src="thumb2.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link2.htm">Longer caption</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link3.htm"><img src="thumb3.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link3.htm">Even longer caption</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link4.htm"><img src="thumb4.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link4.htm">Longer caption</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link5.htm"><img src="thumb5.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link5.htm">Caption this time is a sentence that goes three rows</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link6.htm"><img src="thumb6.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link6.htm">Caption this time is a sentence that goes three rows</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link7.htm"><img src="thumb7.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link7.htm">Caption this time is a sentence that goes three rows</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link8.htm"><img src="thumb8.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link8.htm">Caption this time is a sentence that goes three rows</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link9.htm"><img src="thumb9.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link9.htm">Since we have a wider image at first row, this row must be centered</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link10.htm"><img src="thumb10.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link10.htm">Longer caption</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link11.htm"><img src="thumb11.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link11.htm">Here text also goes down, so if we float layout breaks</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link12.htm"><img src="thumb12.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link12.htm">Caption</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link13.htm"><img src="thumb13.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link13.htm">Longer caption</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link14.htm"><img src="thumb14.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link14.htm">This is a centered image</a></p>
</li>
<li><a href="link15.htm"><img src="thumb15.jpg" /></a>
  <p><a href="link15.htm">This is out last image</a></p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie here :)
Posting the CSS and HTML after a while...

Comment: Try [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) when posting code. It is really useful.

Comment: Dear Side, dear Ashnur, thank you for your input. Post was updated, hope it makes any sense. Peter

Answer (score 0):

You should know what the maximum size of a thumbnail will be when generated on your site, there must be some limit. Why not wrap your  tag into a div set that divs height to the max of a thumbnail. Then align the img in the div. Then you have your p tag below for captions

Comment: Each div can be display:table-cell to align images within